# ViewPager not Previous Fragments while Swiping

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am Developing an application which consists of view-pager,while i am swiping the View Pager, all Fragments loaded correctly, But here is my problem. When Once again i swipe the View pager with same fragments it's loading again, But according to my requirement previous loaded fragments should get restored.I have tried with following code in two ways.

A) Here is my View Pager

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)mMyPageFragment.findViewById(R.id.Viewpager);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In Adapter,

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        System.out.println("MyAdapter="+position);
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new MyPageFirstFragment1();
        case 1:
            return new MyPageFirstFragment2();
        case 2:
            return new MyPageFirstFragment3();

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Second method**

```
private static Hashtable<Integer, Fragment> fragmentItems = new Hashtable<Integer, Fragment>();

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        System.out.println("MyAdapter=" + position);
        switch (position) {
        case 0: {
            if (!fragmentItems.containsKey(position)) {
                fragmentItems.put(position, new MyPageFirstFragment1());
            }
            return fragmentItems.get(position);
        }
        case 1: {
            if (!fragmentItems.containsKey(position)) {
                fragmentItems.put(position, new MyPageFirstFragment2());
            }
            return fragmentItems.get(position);
        }
        case 2: {
            if (!fragmentItems.containsKey(position)) {
                fragmentItems.put(position, new MyPageFirstFragment3());
            }
            return fragmentItems.get(position);
        }
        case 3: {
            if (!fragmentItems.containsKey(position)) {
                fragmentItems.put(position, new MyPageFirstFragment4());
            }
            return fragmentItems.get(position);
        }

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is the code I have used, But I can't retain fragments.

Answer (score 1):

you should not save your fragments into static object.. because fragment manager saves info about your fragments during device configuration changes and restores your fragments after that.. but into new Fragment objects. And your "old" static objects are becoming invalid. I prefer check in fragment activity onCreate() method if savedInstanceState != null and if it is I restore view pager fragments by there tags (findFragmentByTag) and create new adapter from restored fragments.. for Example 
`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onCreate()" );
        //setting view pager
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.mainActivity_viewPager );


        //initializing activity
        if( savedInstanceState == null ) {
            Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onCreate() - savedInstanceState == null" );
            //activity first creation
        } else {
            Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onCreate(), savedInstanceState != null, it is activity start after device reconfiguration.. " );


            //recreating viewpager adapter
            mViewPager.setAdapter( recreateParentFragmentListAdapter() );

        }
```

and
`

```
private ParentFragmentListAdapter recreateParentFragmentListAdapter() {
        List<BaseParentFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<BaseParentFragment>(3);
        for( int id = 0; id < 3; id++ ) {
            String fragmentTag = getFragmentTag( R.id.mainActivity_viewPager, id );//int -> long converting
            BaseParentFragment fragment = (BaseParentFragment) (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( fragmentTag ));

            Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onCreate() - finding fragment with tag {" + fragmentTag + "}, found fragment = " + (fragment == null ? "null" : fragment.toString() ) );

            if( fragment == null ){//creating it
                switch( id ) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Tab2Fragment();
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Tab3Fragment();
                }
            } 
            fragments.add( fragment );
        }

        ParentFragmentListAdapter adapter = new ParentFragmentListAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments );
        return adapter;
    }
```

`
and

```
private String getFragmentTag( int viewId, long id ) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
    }
```

from sdk